# No dll compiled in visual studio 2008 express when built

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, dll, build

I'm a .NET newb, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.  I've inherited a website which I've amended and now need to rebuild.  I've opened the .sln file in VS2008, made my changes to the files and clicked 'build > rebuild website'.  This seems to run okay - it outputs a load of comments in a panel at the bottom as it's building, and then finally stops, saying: "Validation complete.  Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped".

But when I check the bin folder, there are no dlls in there.

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?  I just need to build this thing and upload the aspx and dll files and it should be sorted, but just can't seem to get it to build properly at all.

Thanks for any pointers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a web project and not a web application then Visual Studio does not actually build and compile it.  It just checks through for errors and let's the runtime itself compile the web pages and code behind.  So you won't get a dll in the bin folder.

You can try pre-compiling your site and copying the output up to your web server. 
Cheers Tigger.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're looking in the right bin folder. It's not the one in solution explorer, and you need to make sure you're checking using the "Release" configuration bin folder and not "Debug".

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible they are redirecting the build output to somewhere else.

Check the project properties (right click on the project name and select Properties).

On  the "Compile" tab look to see what the Build Output Path is.  That is where the assemblies (dll's) are going to be pushed to.

Answer (score 0):

Try Click on Solution right mouse ant choose Build solution. It rebuild all your solution files not only the web page.

Comment: I've tried that, but it just does exactly the same.  If it's any use, this is what's output at the bottom pane when built:

------ Build started: Project: C:\...\mysite\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Validating Web Site
Building directory '/mysite/js/'.
Building directory '/mysite/'.

Validation Complete
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Yet still nothing in the dll folder after the build!

Comment: What files in solution do you have ? Only Web site? Or some Class engines also ? Do some screen of you solution.

Comment: If you trying to build 'Web site' it can't give you dll. Try to make your project in Web appliacation instead.

Comment: I thought when I opened a solution it would open as the appropriate type.  I will try converting my website into a web application and see how that goes.  Thanks.

Comment: Using 'Web site', bin folder is used for adding reference of other .dll's used in your solution. building this type of project don't create dll.

Comment: Right, but the code I've inherited is definitely compiled to a dll.  This is my confusion.  Why, when I open it is it now a website, yet when they built it it was obviously a web application?

Comment: @Dan: a web application is going to have a .proj file, which is what the solution should be opening.  Another giveaway is that "web site projects" have an App_Code folder where everything is.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the 'Build' menu at the top of Visual Studio and select 'Build Solution'.

Comment: Perhaps this is the problem?  It gives me the option to 'build website' but not to 'build solution'.  Building the website is what I'm doing, but it's not compiling any dlls.

Comment: If you have only Web site in you solution, maybe because you get only'build website'.

Comment: How many projects are in your solution? Do you have at least one project in your solution that you would expect to get compiled to a DLL file?